# New Questions Notifications do not show up

Tags: support, bug

Not sure where to ask this question, but in the past few days I have noticed that the "New Questions" count which is usually displayed in the Title of the browser's tab and also on the page itself, does not show up. Also the notification for the comments addressing me and on my answers do not show up.

I usually sort by newest and for C# so the url would be:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

Initially, I thought that Stack Overflow's website might be under maintenance but the issue still persists. Is it just me or is anyone else facing this issue?

Currently, I have to manually refresh the page to get the updates.

**Update:** The notifications on the Stack Exchange's Android app are working.

**Update2** The issue occurs on Torch browser, which is Chrome based, but does not occur on Chrome browser.

Comment: I see, how about some upvotes to seek more attention at this?

Comment: It's not working for javascript tag as well

Comment: Thanks @InfiniteRecursion .. Any idea any the issue I am facing ?

Comment: It's tagged as a bug, so the dev team will respond to it and [tag the status](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags)

Comment: Nope, It is still the same for me..

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I'm [not able to reproduce this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eHtGN.png). I'm on chrome 38.0.2125.111 m.

Comment: I'm using torch browser, which is chrome based. I just checked on chrome, that is working fine on it.

Comment: You should update your post with that info, but I'm going to bet the official response will be "torch is not supported".

Comment: Yep. Done. I think i will be switching to chrome hereafter.

Comment: **Update:** I am facing this issue in chrome, my chrome Version 50.0.2661.94 m, could you please check and confirm or this is something which I am facing alone...

Comment: I'm getting this bug too (I get iOS app notifications but not browser ones), from last Wednesday (Jun 22), Firefox 48.0b2 (A beta version, but it wasn't working on the previous version either (not a beta one)). @JiteshNK did you got it working again after some time?

Comment: I am also facing this for 3-4 days on chrome. And i guess this is not browser specific this is a bug.